# Java Cant Change A Label's Text and Check a Variable's State in Endless Loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I have a infinitive loop program enters the loop when a button clicked and this button makes CONFLAG=true and I have another button and this makes CONFLAG=false I want to enter the loop when button 1 clicked and exit when button2 clicked, also I have another question while in this loop program must change jLabel3's text but it stucks and just do Regenerate 
Thank you

```
while(true)
    {
        Regenerate((GENNUM-200));
        Arrays.sort(gend,descTime);
        jLabel3.setText(Integer.toString(gend[1].time));
        if(CONFLAG==false)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Advice: Use `!CONFLAG` instead of `CONFLAG == false`. Also, UPPERCASE words are used for constants. You could name that variable `conflag`.

Comment: @Christian I know it from C++ but was not sure about Java , thanks

Comment: Have you started a background thread to run this infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a infinitive loop program enters the loop when a button clicked

Then you code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread and you a preventing the GUI from responding to events or repainting itself until the code is finished executing.

You need to create a separate Thread to execute the code in this loop. The easiest way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker` then you can `publish` intermediate results to display on your label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.